# GGobi in rattle in R is not initializing

Tags: r, rggobi

Whenever I click on execute button after loading a database in the interactive window I get the following error:

> The program cant start because libxml2-2.dll is missing from your
>   computer.
> Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.

please help!

Comment: can you show us more elaborate details on how did the problem happen?

Comment: The interactive part of rattle relies on the installation of [ggobi](http://www.ggobi.org/downloads/) on your computer. Once ggobi is installed on your system, you can try to (re-)install the R package rggobi with install.packages("rggobi"). The library rggobi, which I think is used by rattle, is merely an interface between R and ggobi.

The issue that you are describing does not seem to be related to R or to rattle, but rather to a missing or broken installation of ggobi.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and struggled to get it solved. The only way to solve for me was uninstalling GGobi and GTK, and then installing the latest version of GGobi direct from http://www.ggobi.org/downloads/ (here you can choose between windows 32 or 64 bits). After this, I installed again the rggobi package, and DONE!