# Rterm error: libxml2-2 is missing

Tags: r, rstudio, rattle, rggobi

I got the following error when I started RStudio (In Windows 7, R version 3.4.0, RStudio version 1.0.143):

```
 The program cant start because libxml2-2.dll is missing from your computer.
 Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took an effort to find out what was causing the problem, until eventually I run onto similar post here: [GGobi in rattle in R is not initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893114/ggobi-in-rattle-in-r-is-not-initializing) and it helped.

The solution was as easy as just running a single command (right from RStudio): `install.packages("rggobi")` (Or  from Tools->Install Packages menu). - And it fixed it !